# Como remover os nomes de arquivo em uma única página?

Tags: htaccess

Na página inicial do meu site, eu gostaria de remover todos os nomes de arquivos da URL, quero que fique somente o domínio. Por exemplo, se eu tenho um site assim:

> www.site.com.br/algumacoisa/principal.php

Na página principal, **somente**, eu quero que ele fique assim:

> www.site.com.br

Quero remover tudo somente na página principal.php. Nas outras quero normal.

Comment: Mas `www.site.com.br` já não acessa sua página principal? Qual seria essa URL que você quer limpar?

Comment: Não entedi muito bem o que quer dizer remover tudo do URL. Talvez queira dizer, não aparecer na barra de endereços o nome do arquivo?

Comment: Talvez ele queria remover os nomes de arquivo depois da barra na página principal @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @UzmkArtanis mas daí não bate com a frase: "Quero remover tudo somente na página principal.php. Nas outras quero normal.", Muito confuso isso.

Comment: Eu não entendi muita coisa, mas isso foi o que entendi @Everson

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você consiga fazer isso com **Javascript** utilizando:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "/");
```

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Não resolveu. Não existe através de htacess?